# How to use a different font-family for mobile users?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, fonts, responsive

I have a mobile responsive website build on Twitter Bootstrap which has a different `font-family` for different elements, e.g.

```
.body {
    font-family: Comic Sans;
}
.header {
    font-family: Arial;
}
.main {
    font-family: Helvetica;
}
.footer {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
#someOtherElement {
    font-family: Times New Roman;
}
```

What would be the right way to override the font of every element on the website with a common font-family say, `Open Sans` but just for mobile devices?

---

**N.B.** I had initially thought of using `Media Queries` but the width of new phones and tablets are as high or even higher than PC monitors so using media queries was not going to work.

Also, I'm open to solutions that require `JavaScript` but would prefer a `CSS` method of achieving this font responsiveness.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  The specifics here matter.  Media queries will work just fine if you're using the right dimensions, but without knowing why you want to do this, who knows if that's going to solve what you want.  It almost sounds like you're providing different fonts for compatibility reasons, in which case you should just have font fallbacks.

Comment: Well, the client who owns the site wants that apparently. I tried convincing him to just add a global common font for the whole site on both PC and Mobile which would be a good idea from a UI/UX perspective as well as easy to implement as I could just use an `!important` tag on the `html` element but yeah.

Comment: Media queries don't need to just be based on screen width (for example `@media handheld { ... }` but Brad has a very good point.

Comment: "N.B. I had initially thought of using Media Queries but the screen dimensions of new phones and tablets are as high or even higher than PC monitors so using media queries was not going to work."

Mobile devices with retina resolution don't report actual screen resolution to media queries - you can play with the device toolbar in Chrome Dev Tools to see. Ex: iPhone 6 Plus is 414px wide in portrait, not 1080px.

Comment: @DavidG `@media handheld` isn't used anymore - it might even predate smartphones.

Comment: @Jon So I guess a `max-width: 768` m-query would be the best approach for this then?

Comment: @AndrewLyndem That works, though it won't target tablets in landscape (1024px).

Comment: @JonUleis Good point, been a while since I did any MQ that wasn't based on width

Comment: @JonUleis That's the issue I was talking about regarding MQs though. 1024px would target old monitors too which a lot of people still use.

Comment: @AndrewLyndem I'd beg to disagree on "a lot of people" - check desktop resolution statistics on Google Analytics for your sites when you get a chance and you probably won't see more than a tiny percentage under 1280px wide.

Comment: Still - it's not an ideal solution since you could resize your browser window and see the font shift occur. You're probably best off detecting mobile devices on load with JS, adding a CSS class to your body tag, and changing fonts using that.

Comment: I doubt there would be that many visitors resizing their browser while on the site though. I think I'll stick with a 1024px MQ.

Comment: @all Thanks for the helpful advice good sirs. Cheers

Comment: @AndrewLyndem You never answered the question of *why* you want to do this.  It's irrelevant that your client wants it... *why* does he want it?  It matters... what's a mobile device anyway?  Who knows.  Pixels are useless here... you could use measurements like `em` in your media queries where `1em` looks about right on most any device... but again without having any idea of why you're trying to do what you're trying to do, who knows what to tell you.  This question is unanswerable without knowing what you're actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Brad Most probably because he thinks too many different fonts on phone would not look good.

Comment: @AndrewLyndem Too many fonts on anything won't look good.

Comment: @Brad Exactly....

Comment: @AndrewLyndem Easy solution then... reduce your font usage across the board.

Comment: @Brad If it was me calling the shots with the design, that would be done since day 1 good sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, with a great android devices fragmentations, media query only solutions is close to not possible. Few tricks you can try out here but ultimately, JS is your safest bet.

1. You could try building out complex Media Query system described in more details at [Css Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) but that would just add on complexity of the code. If you are using SCSS that could be written a bit cleaner for your source code needs, but at the end, output would be the same.
2. [Modernizer!](http://[Modernizer!]) have feature to detect touch events, that would keep your css cleaner, but laptops with touch screen are in use more and more by the day and that could create some bugs in future on those devices.
3. And safest bet a bit of JS that adds, for example `mobile` class to your body tag so you can control your css with it with fewer lines of code:

```js
// Check for userAgent 
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
  // set the body class
  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].className+='mobile'
}
```

```css
.body {
    font-family: Comic Sans;
}
.header {
    font-family: Arial;
}
.main {
    font-family: Helvetica;
}
.footer {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

#someOtherElement {
    font-family: Times New Roman;
}

.mobile .body,
.mobile .header,
.mobile .main, 
.mobile .footer, 
.mobile #someOtherElement {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

You can find more extensive JS/jQuery regex check at [detectmobilebrowsers.com](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/)

Hope it helps